# How to allow app registration to be accessed only by specific user or group?

Tags: azure, azure-app-registration

I'm exploring azure app registration and when creating this it asks me to choose either of following options. Is there a way to allow only a specific user or user group to access this app registration?

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users

Comment: I'm confused because after creating the app registration I need to add permission for signed-in user or delegated (for daemon). Does the link you mention above apply only to signed-in user?

Answer (score 1):

Using **`Role-based access control (RBAC)`** we can set specific permissions to specific users or groups to access and manage resources.

Thanks to ***@[Alex Simons](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/custom-roles-for-app-registration-management-is-now-in-public/ba-p/789101)***  ,  check the below workaround to restrict the access only for specific user or group.

In Azure AD, Create a Custom Role

Navigate to `Azure Portal` => `Azure AD` =>  `Roles and administrators` =>  `New custom role`

[image]
Add the name and description for the Custom Role.
In Permissions tab, search with credentials keyword

- If you want to restrict a specific user, select below Permission

```cs
microsoft.directory/applications/credentials/update
```

***OR***

- If you want to restrict user group, select below Permission

```cs
microsoft.directory/applications.myOrganization/credentials/update
```

and click on ***Create*** to create new custom role

[image]

- We need to assign the created custom role to the app which we want to restrict the users.
- In ***Azure AD*** => ***App registrations*** => Select your App => ***Roles and administrators***, here you can see the custom role which you have created
  [image]
- Click on the newly created ***custom role*** => ***Assignments*** => ***Add Assignments***.Select the user and click on Add.
  [image]
- When I tried to access the Application with the Account which is not given permission, I got the below error

[image]

and able to access the application which I have given permission without any issues

***OutPut :***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to follow the steps from this post: https://edi.wang/post/2019/12/13/how-to-allow-only-selected-users-to-access-an-application-in-azure-ad.

Quick summary of the steps after creating the app registration:

1. Go to Azure AD -> Enterprise applications -> YOUR APP -> properties
2. Select Assignment required -> Yes
3. Go to Azure AD -> Enterprise applications -> YOUR APP -> Users and Groups
4. Select the Users and Groups who should be able to login into your app

Cheers